# Lookup orientdb database version

Tags: orientdb

I have an OrientDB database created using a specific version of OrientDB. I do not know the specific version; this was done before my time. When I point orientDB version 2.1.2 the Studio UI says it cant log me in.

It throws this exception

```
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSchemaException: Cannot add base class 'userAccount', because of parameter conflict: userID (type=STRING) vs userID (type=STRING)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OClassImpl.checkParametersConflict(OClassImpl.java:2388)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OClassImpl.addBaseClass(OClassImpl.java:2370)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OClassImpl.setSuperClassesInternal(OClassImpl.java:459)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OSchemaShared.fromStream(OSchemaShared.java:775)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.type.ODocumentWrapperNoClass.reload(ODocumentWrapperNoClass.java:74)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OSchemaShared.load(OSchemaShared.java:861)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.OMetadataDefault$1.call(OMetadataDefault.java:150)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.OMetadataDefault$1.call(OMetadataDefault.java:145)
at com.orientechnologies.common.concur.resource.OSharedContainerImpl.getResource(OSharedContainerImpl.java:64)
Caused: com.orientechnologies.common.exception.OException: Error on creation of shared resource
    at com.orientechnologies.common.concur.resource.OSharedContainerImpl.getResource(OSharedContainerImpl.java:66)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.OStorageAbstract.getResource(OStorageAbstract.java:143)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.OMetadataDefault.init(OMetadataDefault.java:145)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.OMetadataDefault.load(OMetadataDefault.java:76)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.initAtFirstOpen(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:2871)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.open(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:260)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OPartitionedDatabasePool$DatabaseDocumentTxPolled.internalOpen(OPartitionedDatabasePool.java:140)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OPartitionedDatabasePool.openDatabase(OPartitionedDatabasePool.java:343)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OPartitionedDatabasePool.acquire(OPartitionedDatabasePool.java:313)
    at  
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseRecordThreadLocal.get(ODatabaseRecordThreadLocal.java:54)
```

I would like to figure out the db engine version used to create the database so that I can have a look at the data.

Ideally I would like to continue to use 2.1.2 - but I suppose getting the version on which the db was created is a good starting point.

Comment: We do not log release version of OrientDB but log binary version which can be correlated to release version. Any way could you provide full stack trace to help us to solve your problem ?

Comment: Thanks @AndreyLomakin. I have updated the full stack trace. I am attempting to read the binary version to decide between upgrade code flow . to that end I found this com.orientechnologies.orient.core.config.OStorageConfiguration . Do you have sample on how to use this ?

Comment: Also this returns Null - any ideas ? Orient.instance().getStorage(dbName).getComponentsFactory()